# Using fullpagejs in React, how to trigger function on active slide without re-rendering entire page

Tags: reactjs, function, state, fullpage.js

In my `React` app I am using `fullpage.js` to render two slides containing two different components. I want to run a function inside one of these only when it's the active slide. I tried below code, but once the state changes the entire `ReactFullpage` is re-rendered causing the first slide to be active again so I'm basically stuck in a loop.

My question is, how can I trigger a function inside the `<Player />` component to run only if it's the active slide?

```
import React from "react";
import ReactFullpage from "@fullpage/react-fullpage";
import AlbumInfo from './AlbumInfo';
import Player from './Player';

class Album extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state={
            playing: false
        }
    }

    _initPlayer = (currentIndex, nextIndex) => {
        if(nextIndex.index === 1) {
            this.setState({playing:true})
        }
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <ReactFullpage
                licenseKey='xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx'
                sectionsColor={["#000000"]}
                afterLoad={this._initPlayer}
                render={({ state, fullpageApi }) => {
                    return (
                        <div id="fullpage-wrapper">
                            <div className="section">
                                <AlbumInfo />
                            </div>
                            <div className="section">
                                <Player playing={this.state.playing} />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    );
                }}
            />
            );
        }
    }

export default Album;
```

Answer (score 0):

From docs:

> just add the class `'active'` to the section and slide you want to load first.

adding conditionally (f.e. using `getActiveSection()`) `'active'` class name should resolve rerendering problem.

The same method/value can be used for setting `playing` prop.

Probably (I don't know/didn't used `fullpage.js`) you can also use callbacks (without state management and unnecessary render), f.e. `afterSlideLoad`

Answer (score 0):

## Update

The issue has been fixed on https://github.com/alvarotrigo/react-fullpage/issues/118.

Version 0.1.15 will have it fixed

---

You should be using fullPage.js callbacks `afterLoad` or `onLeave` as can be seen in the codesandbox provided on the react-fullpage docs:
https://codesandbox.io/s/m34yq5q0qx

```
/* eslint-disable import/no-extraneous-dependencies */
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "fullpage.js/vendors/scrolloverflow"; // Optional. When using scrollOverflow:true
import ReactFullpage from "@fullpage/react-fullpage";

import "./styles.css";

class FullpageWrapper extends React.Component {
  onLeave(origin, destination, direction) {
    console.log("Leaving section " + origin.index);
  }
  afterLoad(origin, destination, direction) {
    console.log("After load: " + destination.index);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ReactFullpage
        anchors={["firstPage", "secondPage", "thirdPage"]}
        sectionsColor={["#282c34", "#ff5f45", "#0798ec"]}
        scrollOverflow={true}
        onLeave={this.onLeave.bind(this)}
        afterLoad={this.afterLoad.bind(this)}
        render={({ state, fullpageApi }) => {
          return (
            <div id="fullpage-wrapper">
              <div className="section section1">
                <h3>Section 1</h3>
                <button onClick={() => fullpageApi.moveSectionDown()}>
                  Move down
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="section">
                <div className="slide">
                  <h3>Slide 2.1</h3>
                </div>
                <div className="slide">
                  <h3>Slide 2.2</h3>
                </div>
                <div className="slide">
                  <h3>Slide 2.3</h3>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="section">
                <h3>Section 3</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<FullpageWrapper />, document.getElementById("react-root"));

export default FullpageWrapper;
```

Comment: How is this any different from my code already provided? It's the `afterLoad` that I'm already using causing the re-render, which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Sorry I misread your question. I guess your main question would be "how to update the props state without forcing a re-render in fullpage"

Comment: I've posted it in the github forum: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/react-fullpage/issues/118

Comment: No problem! I appreciate you taking the time to investigate if it's doable. Sorry for being unclear in the thread start.

Comment: @Dave can you please follow the conversation on the github forum?  https://github.com/alvarotrigo/react-fullpage/issues/118

Comment: @Dave the issue has been fixed in 0.1.15!  Thanks for reporting it!